# How Rider deals with C# external dependencies classes

Tags: c#, rider, decompiler

I'm trying to access an external dependency class with Rider (cmd + click) and my code comments on original source code are disappearing during the decompile process by Rider. There is a way to avoid this behavior? I would like to keep seeing the comments of original source code.

Here is a print screen example of class that are showed by Rider and being decompiled instead of showing the original source code:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Example.IEncoder`1
// Assembly: Example.PlayerProfile, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 9BA1395C-E8B1-420E-A723-B1994991D68B
// Assembly location: /Users/user-test/temp/example-project/ExampleClient/Library/ScriptAssemblies/Example.PlayerProfile.dll

using Google.Protobuf.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example.PlayerProfile
{
  public interface IEncoder<TPlayerProfile> where TPlayerProfile : Example.Entities.PlayerProfile {}
}
```

Here is the original source code with the code comments that I was expecting to see when cmd + click on class dependency:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.Protobuf.Collections;

namespace Example.PlayerProfile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Example of comment in code class
    /// </summary>
    public interface IEncoder<TPlayerProfile> where TPlayerProfile : Entities.PlayerProfile {}
}
```

Comment: Comments aren’t code so they aren’t compiled in. Nobody can get them by decompiling.

Comment: Oh thank you for answer @SamiKuhmonen, in other classes when I try to cmd + click it, Rider are showing the original source code. Why does it show for any classes and not for others? Does it have any special rule for some type of classes?

Comment: Do you mean _comments_ (starting with `//`) or _documentation_ (starting with `///`)? Because in your text you're talking about _comments_, but your code contains _documentation_